# filter only next month

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a excel which have all month data. If I have to filter only months after from my current working month. then how to write coding for the same.

For Eg. Now I am working on Feb'17 month.  I want to filter Up to Feb'17. Exclude all future months after from Feb'17

My code

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$:$AA" & LastRow2).AutoFilter FIELD:=18, Criteria1:=">=01/01/2006",Criteria2:="<=28/02/2017"
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Now if you will be so kind to share your code attempt, where do you need our help, and we will do our best to help you

Comment: My Code is below - ActiveSheet.Range("$A$:$AA" & LastRow2).AutoFilter FIELD:=18, Criteria1:=">=01/01/2006",Criteria2:="<=28/02/2017"

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AA" & LastRow2).AutoFilter FIELD:=18, Criteria1:=">=01/01/2006", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=28/02/2017"`

Comment: @Saran try to give feedbacks to answers you got below

Answer (score 0):

for the criteria2 you can get the today date by DATE() function convert it to string use mid() to get only month and year values... write an if function based on the month value to get the last date value....add a function to check the year for leap and add date value to feburary

```
 Month_1=datepart("m",date())
 year_1=datepart("yyyy",date())
 if month in (01,03,05,07,08,10,12) then
 last_day=31
 elseif month <> 02 then
 last_day=30
 else
 isLeapYear = (Month(DateSerial(Yr, 2, 29)) = 2)
 if isLeapYear = True then
 last_day=29
 else
 last_day=28
 end if
 end if
 criteria_2=cdate(last_day & "/" & Month_1 & "/" & year_1)
```

add this variable as the criteria 2 in your filter.... you will always get the last day of the current month with this code.

i haven't tested the code . Please forgive me if it has bugs.

Comment: With DateSerial, last day of a month is actually the 0th day of the next month. So to get the last day of February for example you can use `DateSerial(2017,3,0)`. To get the last day of current month you can use `DateSerial(Year(now),Month(now)+1,0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `WorksheetFunction.EoMonth` to get the last day of the current month (or any other date).

Also, try to stay away from `ActiveSheet` and use fully qualified objects instead.

**Note**: with my tests I've found that if I use `Criteria2:="<=" & Cdbl(toDate)` it works. When I tried without the casting of  `Cdbl` it didn't (because of the date format of my cells), in your case you might not need it.

**Code sample**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterNextTwoMonths()

Dim toDate As Date

' get the last date of the current month
toDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0)

With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- replace "Sheet1" with your sheet's name
    .Range("$A$:$AA" & LastRow2).AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=">=01/01/2006", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(toDate)       
End With

End Sub
```